# How to properly use Xpath to scrape AJAX data with scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping [this website](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&Taric=01042090&SimDate=20190912/), most of the data I need is rendered with Ajax.

I have been at first trying to scrape it with Ruby (as it is the language I know the best) but it did not workout.
Then I was advised to do it with Python and Scrapy which I tried but I do not understand why can't I get the data.

```
import scrapy

class TaricSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'taric'
    allowed_domains = ['ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&Taric=01042090&SimDate=20190912']
    start_urls = ['http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&Taric=01042090&SimDate=20190912/']

    def parse(self, response):
        code = response.css(".td_searhed_criteria::text").extract()
        tarifs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'measures_detail')]").extract_first()

print(code)
print(test)
```

And when I run this on my terminal, I get the attempted result for `code`but for `tarifs` I get "None".

Do you please have any idea of what is wrong in my code ? I have tried differents way to scrape but none has worked. 
Maybe the xpath is not correct ? Or maybe my Python syntax is bad, I have only be using Python since I am trying to scrape this webpage.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your XPath does not works - because of this data is adding from AJAX requests. If you open dev console in browser and move to Network->XHR - you will see AJAX request. Then there is 2 possible solution:
 1. Make this request manually in your script
 2. Use Js render like Splash
In this case, using the Splash will be easiest because of response from AJAX are Js files and not all data are presented there.
Also, I would recommend looking at the Aquarium, a tool that has Splash, HAProxy, and docker-compose